# How to Check Null on parsed XML tags Value

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing, android-listview

Currently i am building this android application and the one thing that has me stumped is the handle `ListView` items all showing in the order i need them but if one tag has a blank value it shows up as a singleLine object taking up nothing but space and spacing out the layout.

[image: Error]

All the space in this images ListView items is a Null string being sent and i parse it.
I would Simply Like to know the best way to handle this Error?

My XML for the ListView Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ContactTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ContactTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ContactTitle"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Cell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/MainPhone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MainPhone"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Fax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Cell"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Cell"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Fax"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Fax"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/EmailColor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to check for the Empty `TextViews` and hide them.
My code is here:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String xml = result;
            String KEY_ITEM = "Contact";
            String KEY_CONTACTTITLE = "ContactTitle";
            String KEY_NAME = "Name";
            String KEY_MAINPHONE = "Phone";
            String KEY_CELLPHONE = "Cell";
            String KEY_FAX = "Fax";
            String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Document doc = getDomElement(xml);
            if (xml != null) {
                {
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        if (getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_CONTACTTITLE,
                                    getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE));
                        } else {
                            TextView contactTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactTitle);
                        }
                        if (getValue(e, KEY_NAME) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                        }
                        if (getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_MAINPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE));
                        }

                        if (getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_CELLPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE));
                        }

                        if (getValue(e, KEY_FAX) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_FAX, getValue(e, KEY_FAX));
                        }

                        if (getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL) != null) {
                            map.put(KEY_EMAIL, getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL));
                        }

                        menuItems.add(map);
                        menuItems = simple;
                    }

                    String[] hashMapObjects = { KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME,
                            KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL };
                    int[] listItemObjects = { R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name,
                            R.id.MainPhone, R.id.Cell, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email };

                      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                      MoveContactsActivity.this, menuItems,
                      R.layout.listed_contacts, hashMapObjects,
                      listItemObjects);
                     setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm trying to check if the value is null to add the object to the `HashMap`. This of course doesn't work and I'm wondering how to check for those `null` `TextViews` and Hide them.

Comment: show me your adapter please

Comment: i am using simple adaptor......String[] hashMapObjects = { KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME,
       KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL };
     int[] listItemObjects = { R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name,
       R.id.MainPhone, R.id.Cell, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email };
     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
       MoveContactsActivity.this, menuItems,
       R.layout.listed_contacts, hashMapObjects,
       listItemObjects);  Then i set the adapter.

Comment: you can't use simple adaptor if you want some list item to be different from another list items. you have to use create your adaptor and then on the `getView` function you can check for null values and simply not setting them to any widget into the list item.

Comment: @William Kinaan If you would make this an answer with information helping back it up i would gladly pick it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to call `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` if there is nothing to show in the `TextView`. Since you are using `SimpleAdapter` and have no custom `getView` method, the simplest way to do it is to use [`SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html):

```
String[] hashMapObjects = { 
        KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME, KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL 
};

int[] listItemObjects = { 
        R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name, R.id.MainPhone, R.id.Cell, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email 
};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MoveContactsActivity.this, menuItems, R.layout.listed_contacts, hashMapObjects, listItemObjects);
SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object object, String value) {
        if (!(view instanceof TextView)) {
            return false;
        }

        final TextView text = (TextView) view;

        text.setVisibility(TextUtils.isEmpty(value) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        text.setText(value);

        return true;
    }
};

adapter.setViewBinder(binder);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your list view item structure.

My suggestion is:

check if tag is null and do something to solve this issue like set TextView visibility = GONE.

Answer (score 1):

As said by William you can extends the Simple Adapter to add the visibility to the view if the text is null or empty :

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView!=null) //reset the visibility if a convert view is used
                convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //text recovering from data source. here I check the name field
        //you can add any test and hide any views using views id and setVisibility method
        String displayedText = ((HashMap<String, String>) this.getItem(position)).get("Name"); 
        if( displayedText == null || displayedText.isEmpty())
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        return v;
    }
}
```

use this class instead of the SimpleAdapter, then you can chage the getView method to add conditions on any field of any views of your ListView.

for information : getView returns the view that will be displayed at a given position in the ListView, you can change anything in those views according to the datasource by recovering the item at the given position.

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid adding null values to your collection which is passed on to the adapter for populating the list view

```
boolean elementFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    elementFound = false;
    if (getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_CONTACTTITLE,
                getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE));
        elementFound = true;
    } else {
        TextView contactTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContactTitle);
    }
    if (getValue(e, KEY_NAME) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        elementFound = true;
    }
    if (getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_MAINPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE));
        elementFound = true;
    }

    if (getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_CELLPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE));
        elementFound = true;
    }

    if (getValue(e, KEY_FAX) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_FAX, getValue(e, KEY_FAX));
        elementFound = true;
    }

    if (getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL) != null) {
        map.put(KEY_EMAIL, getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL));
        elementFound = true;
    }
    if(elementFound){
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
    //I don't understand whay are you doing this
    //menuItems = simple;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check your value with non-empty `String` also like:

```
if (getValue(e, KEY_NAME) != null && !getValue(e,KEY_NAME).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
 map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SimpleAdapter`. It's good but I think change management is key thing of software. You should extend `BaseAdapter` and should handle `getView` method.

I know `SimpleAdapter` is quite speedy to implement but when changes comes, it will harass you. If you write one more file right now for [custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) you will be relax when changes come.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = infalter.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvRawName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvRawName );
        holder.tvRawEmail= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvRawEmail);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {
         if(data.get(position).get("Email")!=null && data.get(position).get("Email").length()>0)
         {
                holder.tvRawEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvRawEmail.setText(data.get(position).get("Email"));
         }else
         {
                holder.tvRawEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//do like for all

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvRawName;
    TextView tvRawEmail;
}
```